# Splash timeout issue on test page

Tags: docker, timeout, timeoutexception, scrapy-splash

I'm trying Splash (in Windows, with Docker), using the initial page for tests:

[image]

For testing purpose, I need to set my maximum time out, which by default is 90 seconds for this page. I've tried this command:

```
 docker run -it -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash --max-timeout 3600
```

But seems to not work for the initial page, that gives me back (for a personal script with long execution time):

[image]

How can I do?